# Reading Drool Rules from multiple Sheets in one Excel

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine, kie

I am trying to **read multiple sheets** rules from one excel sheet.
I used  `kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("{path of excel sheet}"));`

But it is **reading from only 1st sheet** i.e Rules-1 how to read rules form sheet2 also into same session while loading one excel sheet.

**Below attached the excel with 2 sheets format.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drools decision tables do not support multiple sheets in a single workbook. As you found, if you try to provide multiple sheets, it will only read the first.

The solution is to use multiple workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Drools always read the first sheet, so you need to swap your sheet before the kieFileSystem.write()

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("file path");
workbook.setSheetOrder(code,0);
workbook.setActiveSheet(0);//to make sure everything is fine

File outputFile = new File("tempExcel"+".xlsx");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
workbook.write(fos);
workbook.close();
fos.close();

//here do your kieFileSystem.write(outputFile)
```